# Modifying icon after triggering button click in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I want to modify a feature (icon) without using OpenLayers `select`.

1. I have an icon on the map. When I click on it, it generates a button element for delete and modifies. Delete functionality is working but modify isn't.
2. My expected result is when the modified button is clicked it should target the icon by opening a sub-menu on the left panel.
3. When I select any of the options like rotation, sizing, or color, it should target the icon.
4. Right now, I have to select the icon again to make it work. I don't want to do this. I just want to select the icon once which then opens the popup menu for modifying. After selecting modify, I should be able to modify the icon by changing functionalities from the sub-menu table
5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2SVp.png
6. https://i.stack.imgur.com/anWsf.png

```
var iconContainer = document.getElementById('popup3');
var iconContent = document.getElementById('popup-content3');
var iconCloser = document.getElementById('popup-closer3');
    
    var iconOverlay = new ol.Overlay({
      element: iconContainer,
      autoPan: true,
      autoPanAnimation: {
        duration: 250,
      },
    });
    iconCloser.onclick = function () {
      iconOverlay.setPosition(undefined);
      iconCloser.blur();
      return false;
    };
    myMap.addOverlay(iconOverlay)
  
    myMap.on('singleclick',function(evt){
    var coordinate=evt.coordinate;
    
    myMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,function(feature,layer){
  
      //console.log('Feature',feature);
      //console.log('Layer',layer);
      var feature_id=feature.id_;
      var feature_id=feature_id.match(/\d+/).toString();
     
      iconContent.innerHTML = `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="deleteIcon(${feature_id})">Del
                                </button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" onclick="modifyIcon(${feature_id})">Modify</button>`;
      iconOverlay.setPosition(coordinate);
  
    })
  })
  
  
  function deleteIcon(feature_id){
    fetch(`deleteicon/${feature_id}`)
    .then(res => { 
                  Swal.fire({
                  title: "Deleted successfully!",
                  type: 'success',
                  timer: 2000,
                  position: 'top-end',
                  showConfirmButton: false
              })
            $('#tempFacilitiesModal').modal('toggle')
            iconOverlay.setPosition(undefined);
            refreshSelectedLayer()})
    
  }
  
  
  function modifyIcon(feature_id){
    document.getElementById('construct').style.display='block';
    
  
      if (draw_fac) {
          myMap.removeInteraction(draw_fac);
      }
      myMap.getLayers().getArray().filter(function (evt) {
        
          return evt.get('name').includes('facilities_overlay')
      }).forEach(function (layer) {
          
          select = new ol.interaction.Select({
              wrapX: false,
              layers: [layer],
              stopClick: true,
              style: null
          });
          drag_fac = new ol.interaction.Translate({
              features: select.getFeatures(),
              stopClick: true
          });
          select.on('select', function (evt) {
              console.log('HI')
  
  
              if (evt.selected.length != 0) {
  
                  var selectedFeature = evt.selected.pop();
                  document.getElementById('tempFacilityIconSize').value = selectedFeature.get('scale');
                  document.getElementById('tempFacilityRotation').value = selectedFeature.get('rotation');
                  document.getElementById('tempFacilityIconColor').value = selectedFeature.get('color');
  
                  document.getElementById("tempFacilityIconSize").onchange = valuesChangedWhileDragging;
                  document.getElementById("tempFacilityIconColor").onchange = valuesChangedWhileDragging;
                  document.getElementById("tempFacilityRotation").onchange = valuesChangedWhileDragging;
  
                  function valuesChangedWhileDragging() {
                      selectedFeature.set('scale', document.getElementById('tempFacilityIconSize').value);
                      selectedFeature.set('rotation', document.getElementById('tempFacilityRotation').value);
                      selectedFeature.set('color', document.getElementById('tempFacilityIconColor').value);
                      //facilityLayer.refresh();
                  }
  
              }
              if (evt.deselected.length != 0) {
                  myMap.removeInteraction(select);
                  updateFacility(evt.deselected);
                  myMap.removeInteraction(drag_fac);
  
                  document.getElementById("tempFacilityIconSize").onchange = null;
                  document.getElementById("tempFacilityIconColor").onchange = null;
                  document.getElementById("tempFacilityRotation").onchange = null;
              }
          })
          myMap.addInteraction(select)
          myMap.addInteraction(drag_fac);
      });
  
    console.log(feature_id)
  }
```

Comment: Your code is a bit too complex to debug it mentally, but it would be very easy to do with working example. If you post such example on JSFiddle or similar site, you might expect some solution.

Comment: I understand . I will do that